# A Challenging Geometry Problem on Line segment joining mid points of Opposite sides of Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math

I have an interesting Geometry problem:$ABCD$ is a Quadrilateral with area $10$ and $AD=3$. Find $MN$.

[image]

Sorry to say I cannot share my solution here since a lot of typing is required. So I am sharing the link(PDF), in which I have used Appolonius's theorem.
https://www.academia.edu/89570077/Application_of_Appolonius_Theorem_on_Median

Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-bmgzKpmbgVtUcf70mKbZNosL_5WRqM/view?usp=share_link

Now I am looking for better solutions as my method involves too much algebra.

Comment: If you're not going to put in the effort to show us your solution, why would you expect that from everyone else? How would anyone even know if their solution is "better" without having seen your solution?

Comment: I hope there is nothing wrong in giving pdf, its my effort only.

Comment: Can you upload pictures on imgur? academia.edu requires a login.

Comment: oops, I didn't realize that was yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got $BD=\frac{\sqrt{187}-3\sqrt{3}}{2}$. After getting $BD$, taking the midpoint of $BD$ helps.

Let $E$ be the midpoint of $BD$.

Then, we have

- $EN=\frac 12BC=\frac 12BD=\frac{\sqrt{187}-3\sqrt{3}}{4}$
- $\angle{DEN}=\angle{DBC}=30^\circ$
- $EM=\frac 12DA=\frac 32$
- $\angle{DEM}=180^\circ-\angle{MEB}=180^\circ-\angle{ADB}=120^\circ$.

So, applying the law of cosines to $\triangle{EMN}$, we get
$$MN=\sqrt{EM^2+EN^2-2\cdot EM\cdot EN\cdot \cos(150^\circ)}=\cdots =\frac 72$$

Comment: Wow excellent usage of Mid point theorem